# solve $z^2+z+1$ for $z=(x,y)$ by writing $ (x,y)(x,y)+(x,y)+(1,0)=(0,0)$

Tags: complex-analysis

solve the equation $z^2+z+1=0$ for $z=(x,y)$ by writing 
$$ (x,y)(x,y)+(x,y)+(1,0)=(0,0)$$
and then solving a pair of simultanious equations x and y

*suggestion:* use the fact that no real number x satisfies the given equation to show that $y\neq 0$

*ans* $z=(-\frac{1}{2},\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$

---

First attempt
$$ \begin{aligned}
   &(x,y)(x,y)+(x,y)+(1,0)
  \\&=(x x-y y,y x+x y)+(x,y)+(0,1)
  \\ & =(x^2-y^2,2xy)+(x,y)+(0,1)
  \\& =(x^2-y^2+x,2xy+y+1)
\end{aligned}$$
 so  $x^2-y^2+x=2xy+y+1$ (***missing steps, could use a hint)*** so $z=(-\frac{1}{2},\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$

Comment: $(a,b)=(0,0)$ implies $a=0$ and $b=0$, a system of equations. While it technically implies $a=b\ (=0)$  this is not the direction that will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  There is a mistake in your attempt and you should instead get $x^2-y^2+x+1=0$ and $2xy+y=0$.  Then, write $(2x+1)^2-4y^2=-3$ and $(2x+1)y=0$.